# I am using a picture to cover a full size of screen, but its not covering, vertical scroll bar is showing, horizontal scroll bar not

Tags: html, css

I don't need scroll-bar. How to remove scroll bar from the display?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html> 
   <style>
     body{
       background-position: center;
       background-repeat: no-repeat;         
       background-size: cover;
      }
  </style>
  <body>
  <img src="flamingo.JPG"  usemap="#flamingo-map" />
   </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: I fix formatting and grammar

Answer (score 0):

Use the following CSS that will help you, put image path in background-image property. Following code will help you.

```
 <style>
  body{
   background-image:url('flamingo.JPG');
   background-position: center;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;         
   background-size: cover;
  }
 <style>

<body>

</body>
```

Comment: After your solution, my used image is cut from the top. Full image not visible.

Comment: Hi @Hans Raj, could you remove the property background-positon:center; from my code and check it again.

Answer (score 0):

If u need an image as a featured image then u use this code. If u need an image as a background then use the previous answer. Hope this code will useful for u.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style>
            .image{
                width: 100vw;
                height: 100vh;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
            img{
                max-width: 100%;
                max-height: 100%;
                min-width: 100%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body class="image">
    <img src="path">
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Actually, A small portion of my photo is cut from the top and bottom.
image is fixed on the display screen but it's not 100%. and the good thing is scroll is not showing.

Comment: I think ur image is a vertical image, so u face this problem, I suggest use a horizontal image.

Comment: after removing "object-fit:cover" , everything is fine

Comment: That's great !!

Answer (score 0):

```css
   body {
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url(https://i.pinimg.com/originals/be/26/a5/be26a57beb694df3cb91916cafb2d3b1.jpg);
    overflow: hidden;
}

.img{  max-width: 100%;
                max-height: 100%;
                min-width: 100%;
                object-fit: cover;
            }
```

```html
 <body>
  <img class="img" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/be/26/a5/be26a57beb694df3cb91916cafb2d3b1.jpg"  usemap="#flamingo-map" />
   </body>
```